# Can we install BIDS on a sql server 2008 R2 & VS2012

Tags: bids

How to use SSRS with sql server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2012 installed system.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 R2 BIDS integrates only with VS 2008. As detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173767%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on MSDN:

> "Business Intelligence Development Studio **is** Microsoft Visual
>   Studio 2008 with additional project types that are specific to SQL
>   Server business intelligence."

If you already have VS 2012 installed, then BIDS for 2008 R2 (VS 2008 Shell) can install `side-by-side` with VS 2012.